# C++ - How to declare a variable number of files as input?

Tags: c++, declaration

I've got a problem:

When the number of input files is known, for example: 2 files, the declaration will be very simple:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {

  const char* inputfile1 = argv[1];
  const char* inputfile2 = argv[2];
  const char* outputfile = argv[3];
    cout << "Appending " 
         <<  inputfile1 << " and " 
         <<  inputfile2 << " to " 
         <<  outputfile << "..." << endl;
   ...
   ...
}
```

But now the NUMBER of input files is unknown, how to make the declaretion? Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use loops, Luke!

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {

   cout << "Appending ";
   for(int i = 1;  i < argc-1; i++) 
     cout <<  argv[i] << (i != argc-2 ? " and " : " to ");

   cout << argv[argc-1] << "..." << endl;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `i < argc`.

Comment: I see. I was confused because the OP wrote `variable number of files as input?` and I thought of `cat` and the like. In this case, the ternary operator is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array, a vector, a list, or some other STL [container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), e.g. `std::vector<std::string>` for the names and `std::vector<std::ostream>` for the output streams.